# How to give the linear-gradient in svg as a background color for a div?

Tags: html, css, svg, linear-gradients

I have an svg like

```html
<svg>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_124_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="205.2935" y1="707.9475" x2="206.9863" y2="707.9475" gradientTransform="matrix(41.432 0 0 -41.432 -8114.9512 30139.9746)">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0071BC"/>
      <stop  offset="3.780070e-02" style="stop-color:#0071BC"/>
      <stop  offset="0.6151" style="stop-color:#00538B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.784" style="stop-color:#004C86"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9966" style="stop-color:#003B7C"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#003B7C"/>
    </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

I'm not sure how can I give this linear gradient as a background for a button. I tried the following, but I don't know how to give gradient transform in css.

```css
.btn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0071BC 0%, #0071BC 37.80070%, #00538B 061.51%, #004C86 078.4%, #003B7C 099.66%, #003B7C 100%);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* border: 1px solid #00538B; */
  width: 95%;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
```

Can somebody help?
It is expected to look like this
[image]

But i'm getting something like:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `transform`? How it should look?

Comment: If you want to apply the svg as a gradient you can use the `filter: url(#svgid);` property of css

Comment: @MoshFeu Like in the svg you can see some gradientTransform right. How can I use it in the css also? Or is there any way I can use the svg itself as background? I tried using the url method but nothing was happening.

Comment: @CarleB.Navy I tried using filter: url(#SVGID_124_); But it's coming as grey button

Comment: Can you post an image that shows how the gradient should look?

Comment: @MoshFeu I've edited the question with images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a close gradient in css.

```css
.btn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0071bd 0%,#0171bb 39%,#016db5 41%,#005691 58%,#005691 59%,#01538b 61%,#014c86 78%,#003c7b 100%);
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Closed</button>
```

In generally, I'm using the [gradient editor by colorzila](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate gradients from image / css / manually. May there are another tools.

You can use the SVG itself, BUT:

1. You have to make sure that the gradient's coordinates are right and feet to the element (aka `.btn`) which in this case, not.
2. You need to convert it to base64.

In the below snippet, for quick fixing, I created a script that read the svg in the html and convert it to base64 so you can tuning your gradient with it.

Also, I changed a little the SVG syntax, Take a look:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML;
const base64 = window.btoa(svg);

document.querySelector('.btn').style.backgroundImage = `url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64})`;
```

```css
.btn {
  background: top repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Closed</button>

<svg width="1000px" height="30000px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_124_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="205.2935" y1="707.9475" x2="206.9863" y2="707.9475" gradientTransform="matrix(41.432 0 0 -41.432 -8114.9512 30139.9746)">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0071BC"/>
      <stop  offset="3.780070e-02" style="stop-color:#0071BC"/>
      <stop  offset="0.6151" style="stop-color:#00538B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.784" style="stop-color:#004C86"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9966" style="stop-color:#003B7C"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#003B7C"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <g>
  <rect fill="url(#SVGID_124_)" stroke-width="0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the svg itself as the background?